# Taking an object and using it as a source for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have need of an autocomplete using Jquery UI.  The object I have looks like this.

> "last_name":"A" , "first_name":"A" , "email_addr":"A@A.COM"

I have no control over this.  It's how the data is formatted when it is returned from a database query.  I want to use it as a source for the autocomplete.  What I have is this:

```
    $( "#inputVisitorLastName" ).autocomplete({
source: visitorsDrop
});
```

where visitorsDrop is a list of those objects.  What would be the best way to approach this and how would I go about doing that?  Is there a way that I don't know of to change the objects to include the value and label tags that they need?  Should I try to turn the objects into strings?  Google turns up confusing results on how to do that, as well.  I just tried something like this:

```
var intArr = [visitorsDrop.last_name];
```

and the array it makes is just undefined.  I'm pretty new to Javascript and not sure what's going wrong; can anybody help me out?

EDIT: Since somebody asked, visitorsDrop is assigned its value through JSON and vb.net, which makes the database query; so it's made like this:

```
var visitorsDrop = that.getVisitors();
```

Comment: post more of your code, like where you assign visitorsDrop in the ajax query

Comment: It's not an AJAX query.  Javascript calls a vb.net function through JSON, and vb makes the query.

Comment: That's the very definition of ajax...

Comment: Ah.  Well, as I said, pretty new to this.  Kinda got dropped into this project.

Comment: My inexperience aside, I really do need help with this.  I'm trying, but not getting much out of it.  I'd really appreciate what more experienced programmers have to say about my problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to turn an array of objects into an array of strings? Sounds like a job for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)!

```
$( "#inputVisitorLastName" ).autocomplete({
    source: visitorsDrop.map(function(o) { return o.last_name; })
});
```

`foo.map(...)` builds a new array by passing each element of `foo` (an existing array) into a function and using the return value of each function call as the value for that place in the new array. So, here, each object in `visitorsDrop` is passed in as `o` to the function, and you get a new array filled with the `last_name` value of each object.

To support older browsers, you may need to supply a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill).

Comment: That does work to turn the object into a string, but the site's still getting hung up on creating the autocomplete, so I'm probably doing something wrong with that.  Thank you, though, you knocked out a huge chunk of that problem.